# how can I manually build usb multiboot drive without multiboot manager like yumi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, iso

I want to make a multiboot usb drive, but I can't find a good manager to do so. I have tried MultiSystem and yumi. MultiSystem does weird things with some of the isos, and makes a mess out of GRUB. Yumi didn't support most of the isos I gave it.

So my idea was to manual point a boot loader installed to the flashdrive at an iso file, also on the flashdrive. preferably the bootloader would be plop, or plopKexec, and would auto detect isos in a specific folder on the drive. but it would be ok to have to modify a config file whenever I add to the drive.

Will this work? if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pendrivelinux.com has instructions for building a grub2 Multiboot from scratch:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/

I prefer the script from MultiBootUSB, again this uses grub2:

[SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multibootusb/)

[Github.com](https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb)

[their homepage](http://multibootusb.org/)

[Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518273)

Answer (score 1):

since asking this question a new tool has appeared.
https://www.ventoy.net/

from the homepage:

> Ventoy is an open source tool to create bootable USB drive for ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files.
> With ventoy, you don't need to format the disk over and over, you just need to copy the ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files to the USB drive and boot them directly.
> You can copy many files at a time and ventoy will give you a boot menu to select them

though I have had trouble running the Manjaro installer with ventoy, so the usage may be limited.

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.easy2boot.com

Just copy the ISO file to one of the folders (and defrag the file using WinContig/Defraggler (Windows) or defragfs (linux).

Also boots UEFI payloads, etc. Pretty much anything!